# Codeigniter variables

Tags: codeigniter

I'm a codeigniter beginner. I'm using version 2.0.2 with a local server (php 5.3) and I have a start controller with code like this (just for testing obviously):

```
<?php  

class Start extends CI_Controller
{
    var $base;
    function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->base = $this->config->item('base_url');
    }   
    function hello()
    {
        $data['base'] = $this->base;
        print_r ($data);
    }


}
```

When I navigate to the hello function the `$data['base']` array element is empty. Why should that be when the construct function has populated it with 'base_url' from the config file?

Seems that the variable `$base` is not available outside the construct function but I can't understand why or how to fix. Can anyone advise please?

Comment: did you try with a fake string? $this->base = 'test'; on the constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor should be `__construct()` (2 underscores).

```
function __construct()
{
   parent::__construct();
   $this->base = $this->config->item('base_url');
}
```

Also, as other people have mentioned, if you load the 'url_helper', you can get the `base_url` by calling `base_url()`.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->base = base_url();
```

Comment: Many thanks - it was the two underscores that fooled me. Everything then fell into place

Answer (score 1):

Did you know you can do

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$base = base_url();
```

Or even in the view:

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this:

```
class Start extends CI_Controller
{
 private $base = ''; 
 function _construct()
 {
    parent::_construct();

    $this->base = $this->config->item('base_url');
 }

 function hello()
 {
    $data['base'] = $this->base;
    print_r ($data);
 }
}
```

Or in the autoload.php configure:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

and then you can use *base_url();* everywhere in your code.